# Is it possible to write a combination function with recursion technique?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Yesterday, I encountered a problem which requires calculating combinations in an iterable with range 5.

Instead of using `itertools.combination`, I tried to make a primitive function of my own. It looks like:

```
def combine_5(elements):
    """Find all combinations in elements with range 5."""
    temp_list = []
    for i in elements:
        cur_index = elements.index(i)
        for j in elements[cur_index+1 : ]:
            cur_index = elements.index(j)
            for k in elements[cur_index+1 : ]:
                cur_index = elements.index(k)
                for n in elements[cur_index+1 : ]:
                    cur_index = elements.index(n)
                    for m in elements[cur_index+1 : ]:
                        temp_list.append((i,j,k,n,m))

    return temp_list
```

Then I thought maybe I can abstract it a bit, to make a `combine_n` function. And below is my initial blueprint:

```
# Unfinished version of combine_n
def combine_n(elements, r, cur_index=-1):
    """Find all combinations in elements with range n"""
    r -= 1 
    target_list = elements[cur_index+1 : ]
    for i in target_list:
        cur_index = elements.index(i)
        if r > 0:
            combine_n(elements, r, cur_index)
            pass
        else:
            pass
```

Then I've been stuck there for a whole day, the major problem is that I can't convey a value properly inside the recursive function. I added some code that fixed one problem. But as it works for every recursive loop, new problems arose.  More fixes lead to more bugs, a vicious cycle.

And then I went for help to `itertools.combination`'s source code. And it turns out it didn't use recursion technique.

Do you think it is possible to abstract this `combine_5` function into a `combine_n` function with recursion technique? Do you have any ideas about its realization?

---

FAILURE SAMPLE 1:

```
def combine_n(elements, r, cur_index=-1):
    """Find all combinations in elements with range n"""
    r -= 1 
    target_list = elements[cur_index+1 : ]
    for i in target_list:
        cur_index = elements.index(i)
        if r > 0:
            combine_n(elements, r, cur_index)
            print i
        else:
            print i
```

> This is my recent try after a bunch of overcomplicated experiments.
>   The core ideas is: if I can print them right, I can collect them into a container later.
>   But the problem is, in a nested for loop, when the lower for-loop hit with an empty list.
>   The `temp_list.append((i,j,k,n,m))` clause of `combine_5` will not work.
>   But in `FAILURE SAMPLE 1`, it still will print the content of the upper for-loop
>   like combine_n([0,1], 2) will print `2, 1, 2`.
>   I need to find a way to convey this empty message to the superior for-loop.
>   Which I didn't figure out so far.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But if you can't do it, *why not use `itertools`*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Yes, I'll use `itertools` to deal that problem. But curiosity makes me try to solve it with recursion techniques.

Comment: If you want help fixing your code, then please be more specific about the error(s) you're seeing. This isn't a free debugging service.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I've made several kind of error, first by trying collect the data with a list. And later by trying print them out. Well, maybe I shall put some of my failure samples here. Wait a minute.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - example inputs and outputs are always helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do it with recursion. You can make combine_n return a list of tuples with all the combinations beginning at index cur_index, and starting with a partial combination of cur_combo, which you build up as you recurse:

```
def combine_n(elements, r, cur_index=0, cur_combo=()):
    r-=1
    temp_list = []
    for elem_index in range(cur_index, len(elements)-r):
        i = elements[elem_index]
        if r > 0:
            temp_list = temp_list + combine_n(elements, r, elem_index+1, cur_combo+(i,))
        else:
            temp_list.append(cur_combo+(i,))
    return temp_list

elements = list(range(1,6))
print = combine_n(elements, 3)
```

output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)]
```

The for loop only goes up to len(elements)-r, because if you go further than that then there aren't enough remaining elements to fill the remaining places in the tuple. The tuples only get added to the list with append at the last level of recursion, then they get passed back up the call stack by returning the temp_lists and concatenating at each level back to the top.

Comment: I went your answer through in my head today. It's genius.